# WPF Binding using a property as value to define a Binding

Tags: wpf, telerik

I have to say I am not getting used to WPF.
I have the problem that I have a Property that contains the value, but I want not to bind to that property.
I want to bind the property to a property named as the value in the property Name.

This is my xaml:

```
        <telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox x:Name="radMultiColumnComboBox_Part"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1"
                                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=selector, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        >

        <telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox.ItemsSourceProvider>
            <telerik:GridViewItemsSourceProvider ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=selector}" 
                                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                                 >
                <telerik:GridViewItemsSourceProvider.Columns>
                   <!-- This line below is what I am talking about -->
                   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name, ElementName=selector}" />
                </telerik:GridViewItemsSourceProvider.Columns>
                </telerik:GridViewItemsSourceProvider>
            </telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox.ItemsSourceProvider>
        </telerik:RadMultiColumnComboBox>
```

I think mostly a try can explain it best:

```
 public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var sourceProvider = radMultiColumnComboBox_Part.ItemsSourceProvider as GridViewItemsSourceProvider;
        var columns = sourceProvider.Columns;
        
        foreach(var gridViewColumn in sourceProvider.Columns)
        {
            var binding = new Binding(DisplayMemberPath);
            binding.Source = gridViewColumn.DataContext;
            // there is no property DataMemberBinding.
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(gridViewColumn, Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn.DataContextProperty, binding); 
        }
    }
```

I would prefer a solution in xaml but in c# would also be fine.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe use a native control to explain your issue so peole can help you without downloading a third party lib

Comment: I think the question is related to the framework. It seems some solutions don't work for that case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do in pure XAML. You'll need to create the binding programmatically. Something like this:

```
var gridViewColumn = sourceProvider.Columns[0] as GridViewDataColumn;
string propertyToBindTo = selector.Name;
gridViewColumn.DataMemberBinding = new Binding(propertyToBindTo);
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem was I could not access the column. Just the columns. But I can add columns

Answer (score -1):

The solution:

```
        var provider = this.GridViewItemsSourceProvider;
        // var provider = this.radMultiColumnComboBox_Part.ItemsSourceProvider as GridViewItemsSourceProvider;
        provider.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn() { DataMemberBinding = new Binding("Name") });
```